# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown> in Grid Adapter

Tags: android, gridview

I have such bug when I am returning from child activity to my parent activity with grid view.   For grid view I created adapter. Error is showing in adapter.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-26 15:44:29.549 20852-20852/com.pmm.magazine E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)

10-26 15:44:29.549 20852-20852/com.pmm.magazine E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.pmm.magazine.ui.adapter.GridSimpleAdapter.newView(GridSimpleAdapter.java:30)
```

I have such exeption in GridSimpleAdapter:

```
public class GridSimpleAdapter extends CursorAdapter {private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public GridSimpleAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
    super(context, c, autoRequery);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_simple, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ImageView magazineInfo=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.magazine_image);
    TextView nameOfMagazine = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.magazine_name);

 magazineInfo.setImageResource(R.drawable.magazine_cover_sample);
    Picasso.with(context).load(cursor.getString(CursorQuery.URL)).placeholder(R.drawable.show_loader).into(magazineInfo);
    nameOfMagazine.setText(cursor.getString(CursorQuery.NAME));

}

private interface CursorQuery {

    int ID = 0;
    int NAME = 1;
    int URL = 2;
}
```

}

```
item_grid_simple.xml:

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.pmm.magazine.ui.widgets.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/magazine_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/grid_column_min_width"
        android:src="@drawable/magazine_cover_sample" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/magazine_image"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/magazine_image"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/magazine_image"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/magazine_image"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/magazine_image"
        android:background="#d4558b2f"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/magazine_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="magazine name"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can we see `item_grid_simple.xml`?

Comment: From the logcat error report and xml it seems com.pmm.magazine.ui.widgets.SquareImageView  class is giving error....please check properly your project is compiled properly...